# Is it possible the manage tags on Google Tag manager for Virtual Pages?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm working on an Angular project. I'm linking the all pages as virtual pages.

I can collect "virtual pageviews" as seen below:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$window', function ($rootScope, $location, $window) {
$rootScope
.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function (event) {

        if($location.path() != '/'){
            dataLayer.push({event: 'pageview', pageview: $location.path()})
        }
    });}]);
```

My costumer wants to create his own tags by using Google Tag Manager Console. 
For example; 
If user goes to abc.html page(this is a virtual page), fire X-Tag. 
Is that possible without using HTML5 Pushstate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just push a custom event to the dataLayer and make a rule/trigger that fires a tag on that event. Works  exactly like your example (and it doesn't have to be called "pageview", you can use arbitrary custom names for your event).

Comment: So sorry for disturb but i've really need help about this. How can I push an custom event on Google Tag Manager Console?

Comment: I mean, for every tag must I push a custom event?

Comment: No, you can fire many (or all) tags from the same event (or simply re-use the pageview event that is already in your example).

Comment: Hi again, i've tried using the event in the example above to fire a tag using the GTM interface. I've created a tag for abc.html and a trigger that fires upon "pageview" event as given above. However, the tag did not fire when i tried to debug. I have no idea why its not working. I would really appreciate if you can help me in anyway. i've been going crazy over this for days.

Comment: Did you remember to either publish or go into preview mode  with your container ?

Comment: Yes of course. I want to give you a little info about my work. As you see the  example above, I push my virtual pages to my custom data layer variable. And I can see my page urls on Google Analytics real time console and also on GTM preview mode. Then I created a new tag and "Google Analytics -> Universal Analytics -> TrackType="Page View" -> Fire on "Some pages" ->  Page URL Contains "abc.html". So which one is wrong here you think?

Comment: a) GTM is most likely not aware of your virtual url (unless you use a macro/variable that contains the value from your dataLayer), b) if you are doing virtual pageviews the Page Url rule will not work since there is no event (in "proper" pageviews the load event is implicit). Add "event equals pageview" as second condition to your rule and you should be good to  go.